# Problem when using differently sized images in carousel in Bootstrap 4.3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

Here is the demo:

http://67.209.127.195/test/carousel/index.html

The carousel works great for 1600x900 dimension and thumbnails of 600x400. But as soon as some different size image is used the whole thing breaks.

Is their any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your **container** has a `max-width`, instead you have `percentage width` for your **children** elements with `img-fluid` notably. Consider using **fixed sizes** if you plan to get the same width/height content.
And do not forget to fix the size for each viewport depending on bootstrap breakpoints.